# How do I overcome Regen X/Good as a wizard, in Pathfinder, short of summoning a celestial with a good aligned weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, damage-reduction, regeneration

Some of the evil outsiders in Pathfinder have a regeneration that can only be negated by 'good' e.g. damage from good aligned weapons, our natural weapons of good aligned beings.

How do you overcome that as an arcane caster?

Is there any damage dealing spell with the 'good' descriptor that can handle that?

Comment: Hi there. I answered your main question about bypassing Regen, but I'm honestly not sure about if Disintegrate works or not. [There seems to be a lot of discussion on the topic](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2r5kz?Is-Regeneration-immunity-to-death-effects), and I couldn't find a definite answer. Maybe take that part out of this question and ask it as it's own question?

Comment: You have a couple of slightly different questions here. Are you *only* looking for damage-dealing "good" spells, or for more general "how do you overcome that as an arcane caster?" answers?

Comment: Well, primarily by dealing damage. Such as GreySage suggested, or by applying Blissful Spell, such as Hey i can chan suggested.

I know of some methods, such as summoning a creature to deal 'good damage', but that is very unsatisfactory IMO.

Grey Sage: Thanks. I will. I accepted the other answer, as I feel the Blissful spell metamagic is a more general solution, but i might be kidding myself :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/139829/8610)'s suggestion of using the [Advanced Spell Search](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/tools/advanced-spell-search) tool to find arcane spells with the descriptor good is an excellent one. Pick from the results a spell that deals damage and smack some evil with it!

However, if a caster that wants to add the good descriptor to spells that normally don't have the good descriptor so that the spell's damage inhibits for 1 round the [regeneration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Regeneration_Ex) of a creature that has regeneration that's inhibited by good spells (like the [horned devil](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/horned/)), there is the metamagic feat [**Blissful Spell**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/blissful-spell-metamagic/). The feat's benefit can be applied so that the slot the spell occupies or expends is 1 level higher and the "blissful spell gains the good descriptor." This should be enough to turn off for the next round the regeneration of such problematic creatures without resorting to pesky summoning.

Bear in mind, though, that the benefit of the metamagic feat Blissful Spell can *only* be applied to a spell "that targets a single creature." (See also [Aiming a Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) for more on the differences between spells' various *Target* entries.)

This makes the feat *probably* okay to use with, for example, the spell [*magic missile*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-missile/)… as long as the caster's only targeting one creature with the spell, the *magic missile* spell's *Target* entry reading ***Targets*** up to five creatures, no two of which can be more than 15 ft. apart. Yet this targeting limitation makes the feat incompatible with, for example, the spell [*fireball*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball/), as that spell—an area spell—simply has no *Target* entry. Worse, spells that create a ray effect like the spell [*disintegrate*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/disintegrate/) and [*scorching ray*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scorching-ray/) aren't, in fact, targeted spells; [Aiming a Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) on Rays makes this clear, saying, "You don’t have to see the creature you’re trying to hit [with a ray spell], as you do with a targeted spell." This makes ray spells also incompatible with the feat Blissful Spell.

In other words, while the feat Blissful Spell is broadly applicable in the abstract, for this *particular* use the caster must pick carefully which spells to apply it to.

Comment: Dang, that's a really good solution to the problem.

Comment: @GreySage To be honest, it didn't even occur to me to look at specific spells, so when writing the answer and yours popped up I thought *Well, there goes 10 min.* Imagine my surprise when I realized our answers were totally different. Anyway, it's often less intense as a caster to find a new spell than it is to light a feat on fire for something as niche as this, so this answer isn't just blowing smoke when it calls yours *fine.*

Comment: I would have to disagree with the part about it can't being used with a rays. As it purely says there can't be more than one Target: "A creature successfully hit by an offensive blissful spell (if the spell requires an attack roll) or that fails its saving throw against an offensive blissful spell takes a –2 penalty on attack rolls and weapon damage rolls for 1 round." To me reading: ' if you apply to scorching Ray, you can't split the rays between more targets'

Comment: @user3801839 The Blissful Spell feat's benefit begins by saying, "You can alter any spell that targets a single creature to become a blissful spell…." The rules for rays says, "You don’t have to see the creature you’re trying to hit [with a ray spell], as you do with a targeted spell." What *target* means is covered in more detail under [Aiming a Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell), where the entry on **Target or Targets** is separate from the entry on **Rays**. Seriously, I'd like the rules to be different, too, because that'd make the feat way easier to use!

Answer (score 4):

## Against Evil creatures a purely Arcane caster has 2 options

I used [this advanced spell searching tool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/tools/advanced-spell-search/) to look for wizard/sorcerer/bard spells with the [Good] descriptor. I got 16 results, mostly from the Champions of Purity splat book. Of these, 2 allow a Wizard or Sorcerer to bypass/disable Regen X/Good.

### [Burst of Radiance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/burst-of-radiance)

> This spell fills the area with a brilliant flash of shimmering light. Creatures in the area are blinded for 1d4 rounds, or dazzled for 1d4 rounds if they succeed at a Reflex save. Evil creatures in the area of the burst take 1d4 points of damage per caster level (max 5d4), whether they succeed at the Reflex save or not.

This is a level 2 Sorcerer/Wizard spell. Since it has the [Good] descriptor, the damage it deals will bypass Regen X/Good. The targets need to be evil, but that is what you asked for anyway.

### [Angelic Aspect](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/angelic-aspect)

> This spell functions like lesser angelic aspect, except you gain low-light vision, darkvision 60, resistance to acid and cold 10, and DR 5/evil, and you sprout white feathered wings allowing you to fly at a speed of 30 feet with average maneuverability. In addition, your natural weapons and any weapons you wield are considered good-aligned for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction.

This level 5 Sorcerer/Wizard spell is your only general-purpose option (if you find a non-evil creature with Regen X/Good). You'll need to physically hit the target with your weak Wizard arms, but the resistances, DR, and flying speed should work to keep you alive.

Oddly, Angelic Aspect, Greater improves on Angelic Aspect in everyway except it doesn't include aligning your weapons to Good.

As always when using material from a non-Core book you should get GM approval, but these are from an official source so you shouldn't have too much difficulty with that.

Comment: Would Angelic Aspect allow your Ray spells to count as Good?

Comment: @Ifusaso Probably not, you don't 'wield' Rays and they wouldn't match the nature of the spell (going off things like "natural weapons" and "weapons you wield" suggests to me that it only applies to physical objects you hit people with). Rays are always a weird case because they are like weapons in a lot of ways, but also not like them in a lot of ways.

Comment: Do you have any backup that [Good] spells will bypass regeneration X/Good? I know [certain creatures](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/nightmare-creature-cr-1/) will have regenerations that can be stopped by [Good] spells, but I see no blanket rule that applies to all of them.